# material-ui changing the styles of default nested icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui for my app. When I use my own theme, I can't change the color of the nestedIcon on drawer.

Do I have a way to change it? How?

The same problem exist at: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes, when you choose darkTheme.

---

If I set muiTheme like this:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: white,
  },
});
```

the icon will be white, but what I want is that only the drawer text and drawer icon is white, but other text are black.

Comment: are u saying you cant override the icon color manually, or the theme's color is not being set? Also, show the `render` code

Comment: I see exactly what you mean in the material-ui docs page, but the strange thing is I can't reproduce it using a basic example.  Here is a jsFiddle where text and icon are white using the darkBaseTheme: https://jsfiddle.net/a1gov9c3/2/  The material-ui build used in that fiddle is a little old, but I also tested locally using latest (^0.16.4) and it also renders correctly.  I wonder if it is particular to the surrounding HTML or maybe a conflict in another .css file (like normalize.css or bootstrap or something)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set
`width` and `color` settings separated for drawer.
So maybe in your case you'll need to have two MuiThemeProvider-s with different theme settings:

One for drawer

And one for hole app

PS
you can find all possible theme settings [here](https://sm-react.github.io/storybook-addon-material-ui/?theme-ind=0&theme-sidebar=true&theme-full=true&selectedKind=Material-UI&selectedStory=Card%20Example%20Controlled&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=sm%2Fstorybook-addon-material-ui%2Fmaterial-panel)